# how to deploy Pull-To-Refresh ListView by johannilsson

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I have checked out johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh on github https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh .

There are 2 projects in it, **pulltorefresh** and **pulltorefreshexample**.

The example references `com.markupartist.android.widget.PullToRefreshListView` which is in the **pulltorefresh**, I do not know how to link the **pulltorefresh** for use.

Now I have problem making use of the library.

- Copying file by file sure works, but it is far from convenient.
- I have also checked the `README.md`, but it does not cover this.
- There are similar library projects on github and they have the same
  structure, but help files in them do not cover deploying, either.

I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In eclipse do File->New->other (don't use File->new->Android application project) and select "Android Project from existing code".

Click next, then browse to the directory with the pulltorefresh library - if you want the files copied to your workspace then select the checkbox under the Projects list box. then click the Finish button.

Repeat what you just did, but this time select the pulltorefreshexample directory.

Make sure both these projects are open and then select pulltorefreshexample in the package explorer, right click it and select properties. In the window that appears select Android on the left, then at the very bottom there's a 'Library' section. Click Add and you should see a list with all open library projects. Select the pulltorefresh one.

Clean and build the library then clean and build the example.

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: in `project references` the referenced project should be checked